# Google Drive script doesn't work,

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, google-drive-api

I found online google drive script that sends an email with the changes on the prices of Amazon products that I insert.
[This is the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aofk8L6brI_edFc1cGpBQkhtRE1UYV9Dc0Y5akI4dEE&newcopy=true)

I couldn't make it work for 100%.. It work sometimes only for some of the products, and I cant find the reason.
Please help me to understand what is wrong.

Also, I wanted to know if I could modify the script so it will send me an alert twice a day and not only once, as it is now.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful.  Please describe what exactly doesn't work, what error messages you saw or what lead you to conclude it's not working, and what steps you tried to debug the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Configuring Email Notification Intervals

The email notifications are configured as Google Apps Scripts triggers invoking the `priceEmail` function. They're randomly assigned when you initialize the spreadsheet (refer to the `Start_Tracking` implementation).

To configure email notifications manually – e.g. adding a second daily email – open the `Copy of Amazon Price Tracker by ctrlq.org` script associated with the spreadsheet (via the spreadsheet *Tools > Script editor...* menu command). Then proceed to opening the triggers dialog (*Resources > Current project's triggers* menu command) and add a new time-driven trigger for the `priceEmail` hook.

### Script Errors

By default, the `priceEmail` function handles all errors silently. There's not much clue to what would cause the script to *not work 100% of the time*. If you'd like to be notified of the errors, either remove the exception handling in the current implementation or update the `priceEmail` body.

I'd advice making the following modifications (again via the spreadsheet *Tools > Script editor...* menu command):

```
function priceEmail() {

  var sheet, data, page, table="";

  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  data  = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 21, 2).getValues();  // Note that the script will only look at the first 20 rows.

  try {
    for (i in data) {      
      if (data[i][0] !== "") {
        page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
          "http://ctrlq.org/aws/lookup/", {
            "method": "post", "payload": {"url":data[i][0]}
          }).getContentText();

        table = table + tableRow(page);                
      }     
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
    // Following line inserted to include any error messages in your daily email(s).
    table += "<tr><td><strong>Error:</strong></td><td>" + e + " (url: \"" + data[i][0] + "\")</td></tr>";  
  }
  // ...
```